# 4 bit quantization in Gemma-2b

Tags: large-language-model, gemini

Source-:

Hugging-face documentation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8DoT.png)

My code-:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PX9n.png)

My error log

ImportError: Using bitsandbytes 8-bit quantization requires Accelerate: pip install accelerate and the latest version of bitsandbytes: pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes

Note
I have already installed accelerate and bitsandbytes

But I still have one confusion the log say that for 8-bit quantisation I need accelerate and other package, but I am doing 4 bit quantization.

Iam Trying to quantize and expecting model to download

Comment: Please take a [tour] and read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, felt like the accelerate is actually a wrapper of Cuda, so still GPU required. With GPU, I can use 4bit quantization tho.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).